# Should the location service indicator (arrow in the status bar) be displayed when using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges?

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, location, cllocationmanager

Is it normal to have the 'GPS arrow' in the status bar mentioning that the location service is running when using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` ?

Indeed, I don't want this arrow to appear in the status bar when my app is in background (because the user will think that my app reduces its battery life). But I need to track the significant position changes !

Here is the behaviour I have up to now:

1. My app is in foreground (no arrow displayed in the status bar)
2. The user clicks on the home button => I execute `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` when entering in `applicationDidEnterBackground` delegate method => the arrow appears... (what I don't want!)

Please, tell me if it is normal to have the arrow in the status bar when launching `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and if there is a way to remove it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal. Your app could be woken by the OS to respond to a significant location change, and that is what the status bar indicator shows. There's a related iOS bug (Richard Groves's answer) at [Locationservice Indicator stays "on"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872055/locationservice-indicator-stays-on?lq=1). I don't know any way to suppress the status bar indication.